# Propagating foreign key with Spring Data

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I am developing an Spring Boot app based on Spring Data Rest(which uses Hibernate underneath) and mySQL database. This app is incapable to populate the foreign keys of the referenced entries(because I expect Hibernate does it for me).
Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Producto {

    private Integer id;
    private String nombre;
    private List<Formato> listaFormatos;

    public Producto() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "producto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Formato> getListaFormatos() {
        return listaFormatos;
    }

    public void setListaFormatos(List<Formato> listaFormatos) {
        this.listaFormatos = listaFormatos;
    }
}

    @Entity
public class Formato {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer cantidad;
    private String unidadMedida;
    private Producto producto;

    public Formato() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "producto_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Producto getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public void setProducto(Producto producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public Integer getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(Integer cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public String getUnidadMedida() {
        return unidadMedida;
    }

    public void setUnidadMedida(String unidadMedida) {
        this.unidadMedida = unidadMedida;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ProductoRepository extends CrudRepository<Producto, Integer> {
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/x1
spring.datasource.username = x2
spring.datasource.password = x3
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=mysql

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Let's say that the request I am sending in JSON format looks like this:

```
{"nombre": "x",
 "listaFormatos": [
    {"cantidad": 1,
     "unidadMedida":"kg"},
    {"cantidad": 2,
     "unidadMedida":"g"}
    ]
 }
```

The output of all this is that I persist an 'producto' and 2 'formato' without foreign key. Because of that, I believe I cannot bring a producto with its formats

Does anyone know why the foreign key is not being propagated?

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: Edited, it wasn't explicitly being asked.

Comment: Can you include code that actually calls repository to save entities?

Comment: @luboskrnac it is being used Spring Data Rest, so CrudRespository is exposing its methods on API. To call them, I just have to make a HTTP GET request to my backend. For example, to get the product with ID 1 http://localhost:8084/productoes/1

Answer (score 0):

Empty FKs usually happening when you are not setting the back references.

Consider the following:

```
 Parent p = new Parent();
 ...
 Child c = new Child();
 ...
 p.setChild(c);
 c.setParent(p); // this is the line you are probably missing
```

Of course, you can put this logic into the `Parent#setChild` method as well.

Comment: I don't have any Controller at all as I am using Spring Data Rest and I expect to do so for me. See above reply: "@luboskrnac it is being used Spring Data Rest, so CrudRespository is exposing its methods on API. To call them, I just have to make a HTTP GET request to my backend. For example, to get the product with ID 1 http://localhost:8084/productoes/1"

Comment: Oh, I thought it's only Spring Data as that's mentioned in the title.

Comment: if I called the same method(save) in Spring Data, it would be essentially the same output